# Google Home dialogue flow agent authentication error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

Error:-

> Buckets:
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Buckets$List.setUserProject(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/services/storage/Storage$Buckets$List;
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.list(HttpStorageRpc.java:311)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$6.call(StorageImpl.java:272)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$6.call(StorageImpl.java:269)
>       at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
>       at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
>       at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.listBuckets(StorageImpl.java:268)
>       at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.list(StorageImpl.java:257)
>       at com.example.dialogflow.DetectIntentTexts.main(DetectIntentTexts.java:103)

Code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // You can specify a credential file by providing a path to GoogleCredentials.
    // Otherwise credentials are read from the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
    // environment variable.
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream("/home/agile/karan/ElysiotCredentials/Elysiot-9cxxxxxxxxxx.json"))
            .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

    System.out.println("Buckets:");
    Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
    for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
        System.out.println(bucket.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: active this question by commenting here so i get answer.

Comment: As per the error details it doesn't seems to be related to authentication but to a method not found/defined in your code, could you clarify your question and the issue? looks like you are trying to use Cloud Storage to list your buckets, if that’s the case you can use the default service account from [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#service_account_for_app_engine) and follow the sample to [list buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets#storage-list-buckets-java)